# Raise NotifyOfPropertyChange() in BindableCollection when its child items are edited - Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro

This has been a handicap of ObservableCollection where the NotifyOfPropertyChange() was not triggered in the collection even when any of its child item implementing INotifyPropertyChanged is edited. BindingList seems to have the feature. I also expected that feature in BindableCollection of Caliburn.Micro, but it seems to be missing. Can the feature be implemented in any way?

Comment: Did you try posting your issue here: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues

Comment: I didn't, because it's more of a feature request than an issue.